# Impossibility of a Laplace-kind demon

Tags: determinism

Let's consider [Laplace's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_demon) again. We stipulate that the universe whose future he shall predict has fully deterministic natural laws and its state at any time *t* can be observed by the demon in an instant without disturbing it.

Is it possible for the following situation to exist: The demon is part of the universe and can predict the future state (completely or partially) of the universe at time *T > t*, but the prediction he derives is *retrieved* once (at a time *r* before *T*) and ***used***?

In other words:

- the demon observes the universe at time *t < T*.
- the (complete or partial) prediction for time *T* is retrieved at time *r* with *t < r < T*.
- the prediction is "used" (the information causally influences the universe).
- the demon is *right* with his prediction for time *T*.

Is it possible?

Comment: Would the all-knowing demon not have known that the information was to be retrieved prior to time T and included those determined events in the formulation of its prediction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Wolpert, of ["there's no such thing as a free lunch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization) fame,  [showed that](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.1362v2.pdf), if Laplace's demon is part of the universe she is trying to predict, then it is impossible for her to know everything there is to know about the universe, and hence impossible for her to completely predict it.

The idea is the following: Both observation and prediction are formalized in the concept of inference device, and he defines strong (i.e. universal) inference devices and self aware inference devices. Using what he calls inference complexity, he shows that there are limits to what such devices can predict, similar to the way the halting problem shows the limits of universal Turing machines.

His result is analogous in a way to Godel's "No theory can prove it's own consistency", in that he shows that no universe can completely predict itself (since physical inference devices are embedded within this universe).

---

Per the OP's comments, part of the question was whether **Self-fullfilling** predictions are possible. This is already true of the world. Indeed the whole enterprise of modern technology and engineering is based on this premise: Science tells us that in the future we will be able to cure X disease or build Y device, so let us start working on how to cure this disease or build that device. More prosaically, forecasting in finance and in business analytics is based on the idea of predicting the most likely future values of some KPIs and then making business decisions (sales, purchases, stocks and inventory, etc...) based on those values.

Comment: The question is: can we get around that if we demand only ***partial*** prediction? So, are in special circumstances *self-fulfilling* prophecies by the Laplace's demon possible?

Comment: The whole point of Laplace's demon is that it is omniscient (i.e. total prediction), otherwise the answer is trivial. I'm no demon, but if I can partially predict very accurately what will happen to my laptop if I throw it out of the 8th floor window.

Comment: 1) you may predict it very accurately, but not 100% accurately. For example a helpful alien in a flying saucer may catch your laptop while its falling down and safely return it to you. That's not *physically* impossible! 2) The question is not if partial predictions are possible but if *self-fulfilling* partial predictions are possible. So can we construct an example where it looks like fate existed, but in reality it was just a clever use of the determinism?

Comment: Of course self-fulfilling partial predictions are possible.  As Nelson Alexander pointed out, most of modern technology and engineering is based on the idea: Science tells us we can build this in 10 years, so hey, lets start building it!

Comment: The problem is that this is all stuff we *want*. It becomes a *plausible* (not physically necessary!) self-fulfilling prophecy just because we resort to some *"psychological laws"*. But instead of thinking of science, think of the oracle at Delphi telling Oedipus that he'll marry his mother and kill his father. The fact that he wants to avoid that fate just makes it happen. And now we can ask ourselves in what universe the oracle at Delphi could be just some sort of Laplace's demon...?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to accept this answer now. My question was just too vague to be answered correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible. But not demonically impressive.

The demon's "partial" prediction, followed by "causally efficacious" actions to produce a more predictable outcome seems to mix some probabilistic reasoning with some free will.

In fact, this demon sounds lot like a bunch of human beings making a bit of scientific progress, though that is nothing to scoff at.